# Unexpected subelement from Yodlee when sending namespace tag

Tags: java, soap, yodlee

I'm trying to use Yodlee RegisterUser method with the xml below. For some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement table  at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
```

Apparently this is because of the "ns4" prefix attached to "table" element. This seems like a valid xml, given the fact that ns4 is a prefix for "http://collections.soap.yodlee.com"  which is the correct namespace and that table element is part of the UserProfile element.

The xml I send is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
    <ns5:register3 xmlns:ns2="http://refresh.core.collections.soap.yodlee.com" xmlns:ns3="http://common.collections.soap.yodlee.com" xmlns:ns4="http://collections.soap.yodlee.com" xmlns:ns5="http://userregistration.usermanagement.core.soap.yodlee.com" xmlns:ns6="http://segments.core.collections.soap.yodlee.com" xmlns:ns7="http://core.soap.yodlee.com" xmlns:ns8="http://login.core.soap.yodlee.com" xmlns:ns9="http://usermanagement.core.soap.yodlee.com">
        <cobrandContext>
        </cobrandContext>
        <userCredentials xmlns:ns11="http://login.ext.soap.yodlee.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns11:PasswordCredentials">
            <loginName>test1</loginName>
            <password>****</password>
        </userCredentials>
        <userProfile>
            <values>
                <ns4:table>
                    <key xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">EMAIL_ADDRESS</key>
                    <value xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">test1@test1.com</value>
                </ns4:table>
            </values>
        </userProfile>
        <userPreferences xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    </ns5:register3>
</S:Body>
```